# Godot Procedural map, Need help to avoid overlapping areas

Tags: procedural-generation, godot

I have piece of code that using a tile set, i can draw an area of what is going to be a small town/city.
The code seed_cities, make an X number of cities randomly on the map, whereas draw_city just paints the city over the screen.

My problem is that from time to time, 2 or more citites overlap in the map.

```
func seed_cities(num_cities):
    var initial_point 
    var final_point 
    for i in range(0, num_cities):
        initial_point = Vector2(int (rand_range(0, screen_size.x/10)), int (rand_range(0, screen_size.y/10)) )
        range_x = randi() % 10 + 5  # 5 being minium longitude
        range_y = randi() % 10 + 5  # 5 being minium longitude
        final_point = Vector2(range_x, range_y)
        var city_position = {
                initial_point: initial_point,
                final_point: final_point
        }
        cities.append(city_position)
        # TODO check if there is another city before
        draw_city(final_point,final_point)
```

now, i tried to use the function line_intersects_line_2d , but the appears an error saying that line_intersects_line_2d is not declared on the current class, so i have another method of checking if the cities overlap. i was thinking of using that or creating an area2D with code to check if there is a collision.

```
func draw_city(initial_point, final_point):
    for x in range(0,final_point.x):
         $Objects.set_cell(initial_point.x + x , initial_point.y,4)
         $Objects.set_cell(initial_point.x + x, initial_point.y + final_point.y,4)
    for y in range(0,final_point.y+1):
         $Objects.set_cell(initial_point.x, initial_point.y + y,4)
         $Objects.set_cell(initial_point.x + final_point.x, initial_point.y +y,4)
```

Any ideas on what i need to import to use line_intersects_line_2d?
What other way i can check if 2 cities overlap before saving it's position and draw them on the map?

Comment: Did you consider using [Rect2.intersects](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_rect2.html#class-rect2-intersects)?

Comment: Actually didn't know that thing exist, thank you, will try that

Comment: If it works for you, be sure to post your solution as an Answer below!

Comment: @DMGregory, yes that did it!  ty